# Can someone tell me why am I having this error in Python?

Tags: python, initialization, tweepy

I am having trouble initializing the below code! Can someone please advise what seems to be the issue?

```py
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, asset_name):
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        super().__init__(auth=auth)
        self.asset_name = asset_name

    def on_status(self, status):
        tweet = status.text
        if self.asset_name.lower() in tweet.lower():
            tweet = preprocess_tweet(tweet)
            sentiment = analyze_sentiment(tweet)
            store_tweet(tweet, sentiment)

# Pass OAuth details to tweepy's OAuth handler
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Ask user to input asset name to filter tweets by
asset_name = input("Enter the asset name to filter tweets by: ")

# Set up streaming connection to Twitter API
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, asset_name)
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=myStreamListener.auth, listener=myStreamListener)

# Filter tweets by asset name
myStream.filter(track=[asset_name])
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

[image: Screenshot of an error message]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly why you're seeing the error... The call to `__init __` needs four positional arguments that you haven't given

Comment: You call the class with 5 arguments and your __init__() expect 7 and the super class?

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, [`tweepy.Stream`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/stream.html#tweepy.Stream) has four required arguments, which are the exact arguments you're seeing in the error message.  You need to pass those along when you call `super().__init__()`:

```
    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, asset_name):
        super().__init__(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
        self.asset_name = asset_name
```

It's not clear to me that you need to do the `auth` stuff in your class at all; since the base class takes the information needed for auth, I'd assume that it takes care of that itself.